# Rails: TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

Inside app/models/abc/xyz.rb

```
module Abc::Xyz
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

Inside app/models/abc.rb

```
class Abc < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Abc::Xyz 
end
```

When I try to fetch data from Abc.where(id: id) sometimes it works and sometimes it returns this error(TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)).

```
TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
      app/models/abc.rb:2:in `include'
      app/models/abc.rb:2:in `<class:Abc>'
      app/models/abc.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
```

Comment: Can you show full stacktrace ?

Comment: I want to see *(TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module))* in the error stack, that is important

Comment: I would try `module Xyz` instead. Concerns are supposed to be shared among your models, it doesn't make sense to namespace them to an existing class.

Comment: @depa Yes,, `Abc` as a `module` and `class` are confusing.. to me and  Rails too...

Comment: If you try to do `class X ; end
class Y
  include X
end` ---- The same error you will get..

Comment: but problem is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I just want to create module xyz inside abc folder. Is it possible to create a xyz module inside abc folder without writing Abc::Xyz ?

Comment: @depa I got your point. But is it possible to fix this issue instead of changing the structure ?

Comment: first change `app/modesl/Abc/xyz.rb` to become `app/modesl/abc/xyz.rb`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that you will be better off sticking to the Rails conventions regarding concerns:

1. Use modules for defining your concerns
2. Place concerns within `app/models/concerns`

If you want to namespace your concern as in `Abc::Xyz` then make sure that you place it in the right path: `app/models/concerns/abc/xyz.rb`.

Another fine point is that

```
module Abc::Xyz
```

assumes that the module `Abc` has already been defined. If it hasn't it will fail. So maybe you are better using

```
class Abc
  module Xyz
    #...
  end
end
```

Note that I used `class Abc` and not module as your code implied. You can't have both a class and a module with the same name. That could be also why you get the occasional errors. Please see this fine article on [Exploring Concerns](http://blog.andywaite.com/2012/12/23/exploring-concerns-for-rails-4/) as well.

Rails try various stuff while (auto)loading constants but you are better off sticking to the conventions. I have seen many cases where the same snippets of code fail in different points in time or in different environments due to the order of definitions/loading/execution of constants.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. I don't have module Abc. I wanted use Abc as namespace. Because my xyz module was inside abc folder.

Comment: @krunalshah did you change your module declaration to "class Abc; Module Xyz ...` as suggested? Because that would fix your problem imho. If yes: please accept the answer, or give feedback.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't the right answer to the OPs issue, but I think it could help people finding this question when searching for the error message.

For me the problem was that I had a helper defined like this:

```
module Api
  class MyControllerHelper
  end
end
```

But Rails expects the helper to be a module not a class, so it should have been like this:

```
module Api
  module MyControllerHelper
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @knejad, that was exactly the pointer I needed. I made a new helper and forgot to make it a module!